# How to migrate shopify theme app extension from cli 2.0 to cli 3.0?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-template

I'm asking this because I created an app that's not a shopify cli app template. As a result, in cli 3.0, they deprecated the cli2.0 command for the theme app extension. It is not understandable how to use new commands according to the shopify documentation.

like cli 2.0 have these steps to create theme app extension.(take a look below image)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCUK2.png)

but in cli 3.0 description they removed all commands so now big question how to migrate or create theme app extension without using cli app templete.

I'm trying to explain how to migrate or create theme app extension in shopify without using shopify   app templete. so expecting to get an answer around this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. Follow below *steps*:

1. Create `package.json` file at root of your project directory and copy content from [shopify doc](https://shopify.dev/apps/tools/cli/migrate) and paste
2. `npm install`
3. `npm run shopify app generate extension`
4. `npm run deploy`

Answer (score 0):

To classify a directory as an extension, given directory must include a config file with a .toml extension. [Quote from documentation](https://shopify.dev/apps/tools/cli/migrate#theme-app-extensions):

If you're migrating a theme app extension, then do the following:

1. Create a shopify.theme.extension.toml in the extension’s directory.

   The TOML should contain the following information:

   name: The name of your app extension. name should match the EXTENSION_TITLE from your extension's .env file.

   type: Enter theme.

   shopify.theme.extension.toml :

   ```
   name = "My theme extension"
   type = "theme"
   ```
2. Optional: delete any remaining .env, extension.config.yml, and .shopify-cli.yml files.

Comment: Can you pls provide more details. like in cli 2.0 first step is simple like use this "shopify extension create" command. but what should i do now beacause they removed that command. and suppose i create that TOML file as you told me but end question is how to deploy extension?. This is simple with cli 2.0 like use this command "shopify extension push". cli 3.0 have this command "npm run deploy" but as i know that will only use if i used cli app templete.

Comment: `npm run deploy` will deploy everything that has .toml file inside - including theme app extensions. If something doesn't have .toml file then it's not listed in `npm run info` meaning is not going to be deployed

Comment: but i'm not using node js for backend.